# Running vba to sort excel from HTA

Tags: vba, excel, hta

How do I use below code recorded from excel Marco recorder in HTA?

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("M2:M9"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("B2:B9"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:M9")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

I can define the range, sheet names etc.. But not able to set the properties to sort:(

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: What have you tried, and what happened? It would be useful to add your current (vbscript? javascript?) code, and describe what errors you're getting.  To start, you cannot use Excel-specific constants such as `xlYes` without either defining them in your HTA script code or replacing them with their actual values (which you can find via the Excel VB editor Object Browser)

Comment: The error says invalid property assignments or invalid data

Comment: Use breakpoints and find which line the error occurs in

Comment: I think all I need to know is how to put the line
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
            Range("M2:M9"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,     Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
            xlSortNormal
in HTA

Comment: Fixed it..
    Set objRange1 = objExcel.Range("M1")
    Set objRange2 = objExcel.Range("A1")
    objRange.Sort objRange1, xlAscending, objRange2, , xlAscending, , , xlYes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set objRange1 = objExcel.Range("M1") Set objRange2 = objExcel.Range("A1") objRange.Sort objRange1, xlAscending, objRange2, , xlAscending, , , xlYes
```